# Fields under custom object in Cloud Firestore have null value. How to avoid this?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I the have the following model class:

```
public class UserModel {
    private String userEmail, userName;

    public UserModel() {}

    public UserModel(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }

    public UserModel(String userEmail, String userName) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    //setters and getters
}
```

If I use the constructor with two arguments, both fields are correctly populated. If I use the constructor with only one argument, only first field is populated and the second has the value of `null`. In Firebase Realtime database, if a field has the value of `null`, it's not present at all in the database.

What can be done to exclude the fields with `null` values to be added in Cloud Firestore? If there is no way, the presence of these values are affecting the database somehow?

This is how my documents look like:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you saying that you're observing null values in Firestore when writing this model?  If a field in your model was null when this model is written, it will certainly be null again if you try to read it back out.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am saying that when I create an object of UserModel class and I'm using the constructor with only one argument, in my database the userEmail has the value that I passed to the constructor and the username has the value of `null` (as in my updated post). In Firebase Realtime database, that filed wasn't displayed at all. Here is displayed with the value of `null`. How to avoid this? If I have 30 fileds, 29 fields will be displayed with `null`. Thanks again Doug!

Comment: I think you don't want to see null values in your database, you'll have to perform updates using a Map that contains just the fields you want to see, omitting those fields that are null.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, I don't want to see those null values, because are lots. So i'll go with the `map`. This what I was looking for. Please add this as an answer. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make sure that there are never null values when writing a document to Firestore, you can use a Map and populate it with only the fields that do not contain null:

```
UserModel model = ...
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
String userEmail = model.getUserEmail()
if (userEmail != null) {
    map.put("userEmail", userEmail);
}
// etc for other fields...

FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(...).set(map);
```

Comment: Would this work using javascript? I keep receiving this error message:  Input is not a plain JavaScript object. Thanks.

Comment: Since I can't see your code, I have no idea what you're doing.  Please post a separate question and explain what's going on that's not what you expect.

Comment: Here you go! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54293447/how-to-set-firestore-document-fields-with-non-null-values-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in Firebase Realtime database, where non-existing values are not displayed at all, in Cloud Firestore if you add a field which is `null` the result will be:

```
yourField: null
```

If you add a String with the value of `""` (not value at all), the result in your database will be:

```
yourField: ""
```

If you don't want to have `null` or `""` values in your database you can create a map and use `FieldValue.delete()` like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("yourField", FieldValue.delete());
yourRef.update(map);
```

This kind of fields won't be displayed anymore.