# How to set firestore document fields with non null values using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set non-null values to a document in Firestore. There is a way to use Java map object to do this. [Fields under custom objects in Cloud Firestore have null value. How to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270150/fields-under-custom-object-in-cloud-firestore-have-null-value-how-to-avoid-this/48270758?noredirect=1#comment95389653_48270758)The same approach using node js does not seem to work .

Here is my code snippet:

```
var map = new Map();
map.set('userName', 'hellokitty');

return db.collection('users').doc(uid)
  .set(map)
  .catch(error => {
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error.message, error);
})
```

This code returns the following error message:

> Error: Argument "data" is not a valid Document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object.

Does firestore supports use of javascript map objects? Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Are you sure you need a custom object?  That's going to complicate querying isn't it?

Comment: The idea is the just build an object with non null values only easily, without having to build the json manually.

Comment: [json is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) a `common data format used for asynchronous browser–server communication`, i.e. it's more or less a file type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a regular JavaScript object with properties that describe the document.

```
const data = {};
data.userName = 'hellokitty';
db.collection('users').doc(uid).set(data);
```

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document).

Comment: Works great. My bad. I thought I had to use map in js as well.